# Prevent AngularJS from removing data- in attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, jcarousel

I'm building an image carousel using jCarousel and AngularJS. The carousel works great until I plug in AngularJS and it seems to be because AngularJS is normalizing (removing) all attributes in the HTML which start with `data-`

> The normalization process is as follows:
>   - Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

However, jCarousel uses it's own attributes that start with `data-`, so Angular removes these and causes the carousel to stop working

```
<div class="connected-carousels ng-scope" ng-controller="ImageCtrl">
    <div class="stage">
        <div class="carousel carousel-stage" data-jcarousel="true">
```

I'm not using any of the Angular `data-` prefixed attribute names so is there a way I can prevent Angular from doing the normalization process on `data-` attributes so that they are not modified? Or perhaps there is a way to force the carousel code to run before the Angular normalization?

Comment: what you referred to is angular's internal processing of finding which attributes are actually directives, its just saying they take the x- and data- parts out of attribute names like data-ng-bind to see if it actually matches ng-bind. it is not actually removing the attributes from the element.

Comment: it does not remove any attribute its just matching syntax for directives your code have some other problem kindly set up plunker or share some more code please

Comment: ok thanks = working on jsFiddle

Comment: ng- is an invalid HTML5 attribute. If you care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by listing the jCarousel .js libraries AFTER the Angular libraries in the HEAD. Here's an example that shows both Angular populated and manually populated carousels working correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/rWrjw/

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.3rc1/jquery.jcarousel.min.js'></script>
```